# @Override doesn't force to use enum annotation in overridden methods

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, annotations, overriding

Is there a way how to force the compiler to check if I use same annotations in child method as in parent method. If I use `@NotNull` and `String` everything works as I expect.

```
public static final int FIRST_ENUM = 0;
public static final int SECOND_ENUM = 1;

@IntDef(value = {
        FIRST_ENUM,
        SECOND_ENUM
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface MyEnum {
}

class Parent {
    public void method(@MyEnum int a) {
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void method(int a) { // This is valid otherwise there is no @MyEnum
    }
}
```

This code is valid although I don't override all annotations.

Answer (score 0):

To make the compiler check consistency of your annotations, you must run an annotation processor during compilation.  You can do so using the standard javac `-processor` flag.  When run without an annotation processor, the compiler writes most annotations into `.class` files but does not verify their semantics.

You can define your own annotation processor, or use one written by someone else.
The [Fake Enum Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#fenum-checker) of the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/) can verify correct use of your `@MyEnum` annotation at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I need annotation checking in Android Studio and Android Studio does some check automatically. eg `int sth = 10;` `@MyEnum int num = sth; / * without error (bad) * /` `num = sth; / * error shown (ok) */` Maybe all checks are not yet implement...

Comment: You could submit a bug report to the Android Studio team and wait for them to fix it.  Until then, you could use a third-party tool like the [Enum Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#fenum-checker).